# How to set the universal search field in jqgrid Empty on resizing jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

[image: This is my jqgrid with size 10]

[image: I have added filter and filter works properly]

[image: Now i have changed the jqgrid size to 20 but the filter does not apply in the grid and value retains in the search field.]

How can i implement such functionality that even on size change the filter works properly or how to clear the search field on resizing jqgrid.`enter code here`

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used - [Guriddo jqGrid](http://www.guriddo.net) , [free-jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) or jqGrid <=4.7

Comment: version - jqgrid 4.5.2

Comment: The version you use is too old and is not supported. In Guriddo jqGrid we have created a special method which do a search on all fields. On window resize you can easy clear this field. Here is a [demo](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/searching/search_all/index.html) which demonstrates the search.